# Adding event marks to a line chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a line chart with finder set up with nvd3 using the example at http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html

I want to have custom events show up on the chart at specific times. For example, if the x-axis ranges from 10.00 AM - 11.00 AM, I want to have circles/colored ticks at 10.15, 10.30 and 10.45 each indicating a different event (say "event 1", "event 2" and "event 3")

Any suggestions on how to do this or any examples of a chart having such a feature would really help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting for anyone who needs this in the future:

I was able to achieve this using nvd3 itself. The trick is to have the x axis points of interest (events in this case) and feed them as an array to chart.xAxis.tickValues()

Then, for my case, I modified the css for the grid lines:

```
.nv-x.nv-axis.nvd3-svg line {
        stroke:red;
}
```

Then, in order to make the ticks interactive, I used

```
chart.lines.dispatch.on('elementClick', function(e) {
     //handle logic here
})
```

Hope this helps.